# Pubsub API Explorer : Incorrect message data returned

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm learning PubSub APIs. I published few messages to the Topic and when I used [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) to do subscriber pull

`Method: projects.subscriptions.pull` the data does not seem to match what I actually published:

- what I published: `"Message number 13`
- what API Explorer returns is: `NTlkMjdhYzQtZTUyZi00M2Q3LTk0ZTItNTZhNTM1ZGRlODNk`

(attach screenshot)

Oddly, when using actual API (Python Client Library) to do subs pull, things are fine:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(PROJECT_ID, SUBSCRIPTION)
messages = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=10, timeout=10, return_immediately=True)
print(messages.received_messages[0])
```

> ack_id: "QV5AEkw2AERJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNaEGszXHUHUQ0YdHhncGgOQFMAEFl-VVsJPGh-Y3QAVwUfen5pdWJTGgQARHv7z4Dzvb9LZhg9XBJLLD5-PTVF"
>
> message
>
> {    data: "Message number 13"
>
> message_id: "176868380899521"
>
> publish_time {
>
> seconds: 1535000824
>
> nanos: 625000000
> }
>
> }

[image]

Comment: The data returned will be [base64 encoded](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage). As such, when you [decode the data](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/encode_decode/) (this is done automatically by the client library) it ought to match the message that was published. Can you try this and confirm whether the issue persists?

Comment: Thanks! it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubsub returns your data [base64 encoded](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage). It's necessary to [decode this](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/encode_decode/) in order to retrieve the published message in its original form.